# Loading issue thumbnails

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, thumbnails, loading

I'm having issue while loading thumbnail, I set an interval of time for each thumb to load on stage. Some of them can't load sequential in order, they are missing, are lagging...

Actually, I set a preloader to the file size but since I load dynamically from XML, file size is smaller.

Does anyone know a solution to solve that issue?
It's really bug me though...

I load with XML file and don't have any issue with parsing process.

Sometimes all thumbnails can be loaded on Stage, if bandwidth a bit slow it's lagged mean first thumb is loading then it's suddenly skip the second thumbnail, it loads third thumbnail instead and so on...

Sometimes it can load the whole thumbnails... it's weird

Here, I set a timer to load each thumbnail

```
protected static const INTERVAL_TIME:uint       = 1000;
initLoadTime = new Timer(INTERVAL_TIME);
initLoadTime.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleLoadedEachThumbnail, false, 0, true);
initLoadTime.start();

protected function handleLoadedEachThumbnail(event:TimerEvent):void
{
var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

if (currentIndex < tabPhoto.length) {
 thumbnailPositionMC = positionEachThumbnail();
 container.addChild(thumbnailPositionMC);
 addChild(container);


 currentIndex++;
}

if (currentIndex == tabPhoto.length) {
 currentIndex = 0;
 initLoadTime.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleLoadedEachThumbnail);
 initLoadTime.stop();
}
```

}

Comment: What are you using to load the thumbnails? UILoader?

Comment: please post full code, including parsing xml, please.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to create a loop and use the loader's Event.COMPLETE to know when to load the next thumbnail instead of using an interval. That way you will avoid conflicts.

```
var imageLoader:Loader;
var currentImageLoading:uint;
var thumbsToLoad:Array; //array of strings of paths to the thumbnail

function loadThumbs(thumbs:Array):void
{
    currentImageLoading = 0;
    thumbsToLoad = thumbs;
    loadNextThumb();

function loadNextThumb():void
{
    imageLoader = new Loader();
    var imageUrl:String = thumbsToLoad[currentThumbLoading];
    var imageRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest( imageUrl );
    imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadThumbComplete);
    imageLoader.load( imageRequest );
}

function loadThumbComplete(e:Event):void
{
    // do stuff with loaded thumb here
    var thumb:Sprite = new Sprite();
    thumb.addChild(imageLoader.content);
    trace(thumb.width);
    currentThumbLoading++;
    if (currentThumbLoading < thumbsToLoad.length) {
        loadNextThumb();
    } else {
        // loading cycle is complete
    }
}
```

**Edited after comments**

I fixed the loadThumbComplete to take the event parameter. To get the width of the loaded thumb I prefer to take the content from the imageLoader and put it in a Sprite.

Comment: haha was writing the same answer :) @Qpixo You could also use the loading classes from greensock.com , it's a bit of an overkill for the problem here but they're packed with advanced loading features

Comment: Yes I use URLLoader to load from XML file.


// Filename, call it in main
loader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(filename));
addFileListener(loader, callBack);

Comment: @Qpixo That's not the same as what I put in my answer.

Comment: @Knuckfubuck: 
why your function loadThumbComplete() doesn't have parameter (event:Event)? and currentThumbLoading++ is supposed to be in the if (currentThumbLoading < thumbsToLoad.length) ??

Comment: @Knuckfubuck: When using your method above:

Also I was trying to get the width of each thumb and got an error.

imageLoader.content.width => Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

with imageLoader.width, it gives me 0

How can I get each thumbnail width???

Comment: @Qpixo see my edited answer above. currentThumbLoading++ is fine where it is. It should increment before the cycle checks if it should continue or not.

Comment: @Qpixo if my answer helped you solve it, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I have declared tabPhoto and tabThumbWidthIncrement as Vector

```
var tabPhoto:Vector.<ThumbInfo> = new Vector.<ThumbInfo>;
var tabThumbWidthIncrement:Vector<uint> = new Vector.<uint>;
```